# How to prevent a player from moving through walls in Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've got the following player controller:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using System.Collections;

[RequireComponent(typeof(NetworkIdentity))]
public class PlayerController : NetworkBehaviour {
    public Vector3 size = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
    public float speed = 10;
    public float rotateSpeed = 9;

    private Transform _transform;
    private Map _map;
    private BoxCollider _collider;
    private bool _active = false;

    private Vector3 _lastPosition;
    private bool _isGrounded = false;

    void Start () {
        _transform = transform;
        Messenger.AddListener ("MAP_LOADED", OnMapLoaded);

        _transform.localPosition = new Vector3 (-100, -100, -100);

        gameObject.name = "Player " + gameObject.GetComponent<NetworkIdentity> ().netId.Value;
        _collider = gameObject.GetComponent<BoxCollider> ();
        _map = GameObject.Find ("Map").GetComponent<Map> ();

        _collider.size = size;
    }

    void OnMapLoaded () {
        if (isLocalPlayer) {
            // Hook up the camera
            PlayerCamera cam = Camera.main.GetComponent<PlayerCamera>();
            cam.target = transform;

            // Move the player to the it's spawn location
            _transform.localPosition = _map.GetPlayerSpawn();
        }

        // Set the player as active
        _active = true;
    }

    void Update () {
        if (!isLocalPlayer || !_active) {
            return;
        }

        _lastPosition = _transform.position;

        float transAmount = speed * Time.deltaTime;
        float rotateAmount = rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

        if (Input.GetKey ("up")) {
            transform.Translate (0, 0, transAmount);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey ("down")) {
            transform.Translate (0, 0, -transAmount);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey ("left")) {
            transform.Rotate (0, -rotateAmount, 0);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey ("right")) {
            transform.Rotate (0, rotateAmount, 0);
        }

        if (!_isGrounded) {
            Vector3 down = _transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.down);
            _transform.position += down * Time.deltaTime * _map.gravity;
        }
    }

    void FixedUpdate () {
        //
        // Check what is below us
        //
        Vector3 down = _transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.down);
        RaycastHit[] hits;
        hits = Physics.RaycastAll(_transform.position, down, size.y + 0.001f);

        _isGrounded = false;
        foreach (RaycastHit hit in hits) {
            if (hit.collider.gameObject.tag.ToUpper() == "GROUND") {
                _isGrounded = true;
            }
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider) {
        Debug.Log ("Triggered by " + collider.gameObject.tag.ToUpper ());
        if (collider.gameObject.tag.ToUpper () == "GROUND") {
            transform.position = _lastPosition;
        }
    }

}
```

In `Update` I'm taking the user's input and moving the transform around. In `FixedUpdate` I'm checking to see if the player is on the ground and setting a flag appropriately. And finally in `OnTriggerEnter` I'm checking to see if I'm trying to go through anything.

If in `OnTriggerEnter` I hit something I try to set the player's position back to a good one, but that's not happening. My guess is because `_lastPosition` isn't what I'm expecting it to be.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use [rigidbody.Move(position)](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html) instead of [transform.Translate(position)](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html).

Note: Using transform.translate causing performance issues and you must handle collision detection manually.